# Requirejs load timeout issue - how to increase the time?

Tags: debugging, requirejs

I have a requirejs project.

While debugging it in chrome i put breakpoints in the code and usually i go slowly through the code. But this causes timeout errors for the future files.

How can i increase the timeout time for the files to like 50 seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `waitSeconds` config option.

```javascript
require.config({
    baseUrl: "./scripts",
    waitSeconds: 50,
    paths: {
        // ...
    },
    // ...
});
```